# Moving Shape in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to develop the project and for the moment I am doing simple tasks. I want to move some of the drawings I drew on the screen.

My problem is that I draw some Rect objects and a path and when I execute it, just the rectangles are moving.

When I move the rectangle, in each execution the rectangle drawn is removed and the "new one" is painted, but it does not happen with the path.

Sorry for my poor explanation, here is some code:

```
   public void run(){

        preparePaint();

        while(CanDraw){

            if ( !surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }


            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            if ( ini == true ){ SenStart(canvas); ini = false;}

             canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);


            rectangle0.set(sensor0.left, sensor0.top, sensor0.right, sensor0.bottom);

            motion();

            canvas.drawRect(rectangle0, red_fill);

            canvas.drawPath(wallpath, red_fill);

            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }
    }
```

This is the initialization of the drawings:

```
   protected void SenStart(Canvas canvas){

        robot.x1 = getWidth() /2 - 100;
        robot.y1 = getHeight()/2 + 40; 
        robot.x2 = getWidth() /2 - 100;
        robot.y2 = getHeight()/2 -80; 
        robot.x3 = getWidth()/2;
        robot.y3 = getHeight()/2 -140;
        robot.x4 = getWidth() /2 + 100; 
        robot.y4 = getHeight()/2 -80; 
        robot.x5 = getWidth() / 2 + 100;
        robot.y5 = getHeight() / 2 + 40;

        wallpath.moveTo( robot.x1,  robot.y1); // used for first point
        wallpath.lineTo( robot.x2,  robot.y2);
        wallpath.lineTo( robot.x3,  robot.y3);
        wallpath.lineTo( robot.x4,  robot.y4);
        wallpath.lineTo( robot.x5,  robot.y5);
        wallpath.lineTo( robot.x1,  robot.y1); // used for first point

        sensor0.left = getWidth() /2 - 150;
        sensor0.bottom = getHeight()/2 - 20;
        sensor0.right = getWidth()/2 - 130;
        sensor0.top = getHeight()/2;

    }
}
```

Here is where I add motion to these objects:

```
private void motion (){

   robot.y1 = robot.y1 -1;
   robot.y2 = robot.y2 -1;
   robot.y3 = robot.y3 -1;
   robot.y4 = robot.y4 -1;
   robot.y5 = robot.y5 -1;

    wallpath.moveTo(robot.x1, robot.y1); // used for first point
    wallpath.lineTo( robot.x2,  robot.y2);
    wallpath.lineTo( robot.x3,  robot.y3);
    wallpath.lineTo( robot.x4,  robot.y4);
    wallpath.lineTo( robot.x5,  robot.y5);
    wallpath.lineTo( robot.x1,  robot.y1); // used for first point

    sensor0.top     = sensor0.top -1;
    sensor0.bottom  = sensor0.bottom -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone could need it, to remove this path of the screen you need to write 
`nameofthepath.reset()` before you write new points.